# CSS positioning issue. Element not Displayed where Called

Tags: css, wordpress

So, CSS is not my strength. I need some help.  I'm developing a Wordpress Plugin, and while I have the PHP down, I need help with getting the CSS to work with me. The page can be seen at http://www.airupt.com/?page_id=386.  The issue is that I have called a shortcode for the search box below the call for the search results.  This is for demo purposes only and the link will die soon after this is fixed.

Please type something in and search, you will see what I mean.  The Search box background will appear at the top of the results, over the first one.  The search box itself will appear after the results, as expected.

Can anyone tell me where the code went wrong and how it can be fixed?  :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get a better response if you include a limited test case of the code in question here rather than just pointing us at your dev page. Also tell us what you have tried. You may want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing this in more than one browser? It doesn't seem like it. To answer your question:

give it a `float:left;`, like the rest of the elements in the `<div class="entry">`

```
.search-custom {
    float:left;
    /* all the other styles for search-custom that it normally has*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say rather set `clear:both` on `.search-custom`.

`overflow:hidden` will get you into more/different trouble because your sizes are a bit out

Comment: Thanks, mate.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow:hidden;` on your `.search-custom` div, then go get yourself a copy of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It'll get you out of 80% of these jams.

Comment: Got firebug.  Unfortunately, my normal machine is in the shop, so I don't have access to all the tools I normally do.

Comment: Bummer, man. Do you use Chrome? If so, it comes pre-loaded with a Firebug - like tool. Hit `ctrl + shift + i` to access it.